# Gradient progress bar with rounded corners SpriteKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to build a gradient progress bar with rounded corners in SpriteKit, but I'm completely stuck at this point. I've tried different combinations of SKCropNode, SKShapeNodes etc. but I can't seem to get it to work.
Any help is appreciated, kind regards!

Comment: When posting here, always try to follow the guide about [how to ask a (good) question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cause questions like this are often closed due to not complying with SO standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about SKCropNode + its maskNode property. From the docs:

> SKCropNode is a container node that you use to crop other nodes in the
> scene. You add other nodes to a crop node and set the crop node's
> maskNode property. For example, here are some ways you might specify a
> mask:
>
> An untextured sprite that limits content to a rectangular portion of
> the scene.
>
> A textured sprite that works as a precise per-pixel mask.
>
> A collection of child nodes that form a unique shape.
>
> You can animate the shape or contents of the mask to implement
> interesting effects such as hiding or revealing.

So, a simple example would be like this:

```
    class GameScene: SKScene {
        
        override func sceneDidLoad() {
            
            super.sceneDidLoad()
            createProgressBar()
        }
        
        private func createProgressBar(){
            
            let barFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 15)
            
            if let cgImage = createImage(frame: barFrame) {
                
                let texture = SKTexture(cgImage: cgImage)
                
                let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
                let cropNode = SKCropNode()
                let mask = SKSpriteNode(color: .gray, size: barFrame.size)
                
                cropNode.addChild(sprite)
                cropNode.maskNode = mask
                
                sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
                mask.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
                
                var counter:Double = 0
                let action = SKAction.run {[weak self, sprite] in
                    guard let `self` = self, counter < 100 else {
                    sprite?.removeAction(forKey: "loop")
                      return
                
                  }
                    
                    counter += 1
                    let newWidth = self.getWidth(percents: counter, spriteWidth: barFrame.width)
                    print("Bar width \(newWidth), percentage \(counter)")
                    
                    mask.size = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: barFrame.height)
                }
                let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.05)
                let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, action])
                
                let loop = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)
                
                
                
                addChild(cropNode)
                cropNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2.0, y: self.frame.height / 2.0)
                
                sprite.run(loop, withKey: "loop")
                
                
            }
        }
        
        private func getWidth(percents:Double, spriteWidth:Double)->Double{
            
            let onePercent = spriteWidth / 100.0
            
            return onePercent * percents
        }
        
        
        private func createImage(frame barFrame:CGRect) -> CGImage?{
            
            if let ciFilter = CIFilter(name: "CILinearGradient"){
                
                let ciContext = CIContext()
                
                ciFilter.setDefaults()
                
                let startColor  = CIColor(red: 0.75, green: 0.35, blue: 0.45, alpha: 1)
                let endColor    = CIColor(red: 0.45, green: 0.35, blue: 0.75, alpha: 1)
                
                let startVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: 0)
                let endVector   = CIVector(x: barFrame.width, y: 0)
                
                ciFilter.setValue(startColor,   forKey: "inputColor0")
                ciFilter.setValue(endColor,     forKey: "inputColor1")
                ciFilter.setValue(startVector,  forKey: "inputPoint0")
                ciFilter.setValue(endVector,    forKey: "inputPoint1")
                
                if let outputImage = ciFilter.outputImage {
                    let  cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(outputImage, from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: barFrame.width, height: barFrame.height))
                    return  cgImage
                    
                }
            }
            
            return nil
      

  }
}
```

Now cause this is just an example I won't go all the way to implement this right, but You can maybe make a class of it with  designable and inspectable properties, optimize code, make it reusable etc. But the general idea is shown here.

You use `SKCropNode` to add progress bar in it, and use `maskNode` property to reveal progress bar as percentage increases. Also I gave a method to create texture programatically, but You can use just a .png file instead.

Crop node is here used only cause of a gradient (cause we don't wan't to scale image, but rather to show it part by part). Obviously, crop node is not needed if a progress bar had only one color.

Here is final result:

[image: progress-bar]

Comment: This is amazing! Absolutely amazing! Thank you very much for taking the time!